# Is there a way to customize the UIPrintInteractionController elements (eg. remove the preview)?

Tags: ios, uiprintinteractioncntrler

From what I see going through the UIPrintInteractionController and the UIPrintInfo documentation, there is no direct way of changing the content of the view. 
What I specifically need is to remove the preview of the document or at least the pan and zoom gesture that will let you open the document and share it.
Can I remove that view or implement a custom view inside the controller?
thank you